# Animating the visibility of a BottomBar leads to "jumping" ui in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I'm writing an android-app using jetpack compose.

This app has a bottom bar which i would like to hide sometimes using an animation.
However, this proved challenging: as soon as i was dealing with a scrollable screen, there was some "jumping" of my ui - see end of post.

My minimal example looks like:

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun JumpingBottomBarScreen() {
    var bottomBarVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Scaffold(
        content = { padding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
                    .padding(padding)
            ) {
                (1..20).forEach { Text(text = "Test #$it of 50") }

                Button(
                    onClick = { bottomBarVisible = !bottomBarVisible },
                    content = { Text(if (bottomBarVisible) "Hide Bottom Bar" else "Show Bottom Bar") }
                )

                (21..50).forEach { Text(text = "Test #$it of 50") }
            }
        },
        bottomBar = {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = bottomBarVisible,
                enter = slideInVertically(initialOffsetY = { it }),
                exit = slideOutVertically(targetOffsetY = { it })
            ) {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color.Red)
                )
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Avoiding `AnimatedVisibility` in favor of just offsetting works better, however, i only managed for fixed height bottom-bars, which makes this much less fail-safe.

```
bottomBar = {
    val bottomBarOffset by animateDpAsState(targetValue = if (bottomBarVisible) 0.dp else 50.dp)

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .offset(y = bottomBarOffset)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp)
            .background(Color.Red)
    )
}
```

How do i do this cleanly?
I'm fine with my screen having more padding at the bottom than expected.

---

Bad on the left/top, good (but fixed height) on the right/bottom

[image: bad]

[image: good]

Comment: What about using `BottomSheetScaffold`?

Comment: I'm stuck in this situation as well, I think we are missing something to get AnimatedVisibility to work with the rest of the UI

Comment: Welcome to the club. Turns out, this happens only if you are at the bottom of the list. As it changes the content size, it will be passed to the LazyListState and once the content size is restored, it won't reapply the list state as the top was damaged the the content expansion already. Sad story, no solution though :(

Comment: the same behavior if you use animation for switching between screens, though bottom bar without animation, it's bigger issue, offsetting won't help, cause animations happens within NavHost

Answer (score 1):

You need to animate your Column padding as well:

```
@Composable
fun NotJumpingBottomBarScreen() {
    var bottomBarVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val bottomBarOffset by animateDpAsState(targetValue = if (bottomBarVisible) 0.dp else 50.dp)

    Scaffold(
        content = { padding ->
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.LightGray)
                    .padding(
                        start = padding.calculateStartPadding(LocalLayoutDirection.current),
                        top = padding.calculateTopPadding(),
                        end = padding.calculateEndPadding(LocalLayoutDirection.current),
                        bottom = padding.calculateBottomPadding() - bottomBarOffset
                    )
            ) {
                (1..20).forEach { Text(text = "Test #$it of 50") }

                Button(
                    onClick = { bottomBarVisible = !bottomBarVisible },
                    content = { Text(if (bottomBarVisible) "Hide Bottom Bar" else "Show Bottom Bar") }
                )

                (21..50).forEach { Text(text = "Test #$it of 50") }
            }
        },
        bottomBar = {
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .offset(y = bottomBarOffset)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .offset(y = bottomBarOffset)
                    .background(Color.Red)
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: ` .offset(y = bottomBarOffset)` - was called two times, also bottom bar is still visible under transparent navigation bars

Comment: `50.dp + WindowInsets.navigationBars.getBottom(LocalDensity.current).dp` - the solution so it would not be behind transparent navigation bars

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the inner padding from the Scaffold content, and control each screen's padding individually, it solves this issue.

```
Scaffold(
    content = { padding ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .padding(padding) <--------------- Don't do this
        ) {
            // column content
        }
    },
    // other parameters
)
```